# PHP Export Excel to specific Path?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, usb, export

Is it possible to export a PHP MySQL Excel sheet to a specified path such as USB Flash Drive.
Its because I'm using php as Point of Sale and all What i want now is once you click on a Button- it will collects records from MySQL database and exports it as excel or csv file to a USB Flash Drive.

I've tried to Google it out, but I can't seem to find anything.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you mean save to USB flash drive in the background? If you're forcing output you get a file save dialog and then you can choose the location to save. can't you?

Comment: Yes i want to save it to USB flash drive. Well i thought if there is a way to create and save excel file quickly. But either way, how would i do it ?

Comment: @AliHamra Please accept an answer by clicking on the tick under the arrows if you are happy with one or post extra information in order for users to help you better if you are still having problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write the file. To write to usb drive you just need to specify correct file path. If you're on *nix it would be like `/media/USB/` on linux or `/Volumes/USB/` on Mac. For Windows it would be like `F:/`.

so rough example is like

```
$a = array('1','2','3'); //This is imaginable row from MySQL
$f = fopen('F:/mycsv.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($f, $a);
fclose($f);
```

Manual for `fputcsv` is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

If needed, you can ask user for a file path in any way supported by your application.

Comment: Thank You ! I'll try to work on that, but what if "mycsv.csv" file is not there? How can to create one via PHP? and If exists, it should not over-write the csv file. And I'm using Windows.

Comment: The given example will create the file or overwrite existing one. Note the second argument to [fopen](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

Comment: AliHamra, my example will work if you know the path. If you want to just give an ability for user to save the file at any path (including USB drive or even network drive) - take a look at @mrmryb solution.

Comment: Does this actually work? He wants to save the file to a portable usb, `fopen('F:/mycsv.csv', 'w');` would save the file on the server and not output data to the browser?

Comment: He said he's using PHP on Point Of Sale so I assume it just runs locally.

Answer (score 0):

Not a simple process to save it as excel, but relatively straightforward to write a csv.

```
$temp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),'tmp');
$handle = fopen($temp,'w');
$query = $pdo->prepare("select * from table");
$query->execute();
$row=$statement->fetch();
$keys=array_keys($row);
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export_'.date('dmY').'.csv');
fputcsv($handle,$keys);
while($row){
fputcsv($handle,$row);
$row=$statement->fetch();}
echo file_get_contents($temp);
fclose($handle);
```

This creates a temporary file in your temp folder, you write the csv to that and then give it csv headers and echo it out which gives the user a save file box.
I call $row once before the loop to get the table columns with array_keys and output those first and then loop through with a while calling $row=$statement->fetch() at the end of the loop.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated. See [here](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated)

Comment: I'm not recommending this be copied word for word, but the basic principles of creating a csv file are what he asked for and there they are, I'm sure he's got his querys written already.

Comment: I agree, but apparently in this case the code will copied word to word and then you will get question "why it doesn't work" :)

Comment: I've added in an note just to make sure that doesn't happen, I do agree with you that it is better for the poster to be aware of this.

Comment: Why not instead of creating temporary file, writing it and then reading, just open file as `php://output` and simply output csv to browser?

Comment: @zysoft If you open file as php://output would you not still need to write, and then output file contents as I have suggested, there still needs to be a file to be opened? As his question states, he wants to get the records from a table and output those to a csv, he does not have a csv ready. No really sure how your technique would work but if you would like to add an edited example on to the end of my answer feel free to.

Comment: Added, but it looks it has been declined. Why?

Comment: @zysoft Seems like it was rejected by other users.