# PHP Export to CSV

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv, export

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Export Excel to specific Path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305204/php-export-excel-to-specific-path)

I'm not really familiar with PHP exporting to excel or csv, but I'm using PHP MySQL for a local point of sale.
According to the code below, this actually works..But not in the way it should be ! All records are placed as 1 row inside the csv file, how can i fix that ? Also, How would I stop overwriting the same file...I mean When I click on a Button to export the csv, it should check if there is an existing csv file, If there is--Create new one !

Thank You

```
require_once('connect_db.php');

$items_array = array();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sold_items");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $items_array[] = $row['item_no'];

    $items_array[] = $row['qty'];
}

$f = fopen('C:/mycsv.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($f, $items_array);
fclose($f);
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to add line terms after each line. How are you viewing the resultant file? Maybe the terms are there but linux/windows specific. Also - viewing via a browser will only break lines using html.

Comment: and what does create a new one mean ? what would happen to the old one ?

Comment: @ethrbunny Exactly, I'm looking for add line..As I have mentioned before, they are all viewed as 1 row when opening csv file. I'm using Windows and i'm not looking to output the results via a browser...All i need to see is 2 colums, "item_no" and "Qty" with the rest of the items and qty below.

Comment: @jidma I mean creating another csv file, What happens now is that when i click the button to export values to csv,  the file will be created in C directory. But when clicking of the same button, it will deletes everything inside that row and adds the new values...All i want to see "n" csv file when clicking "n" of buttons....Hope that makes sense!

Comment: @AliHamra yep, you need to specifies that each file would have a different name (mycsv1.csv, mycsv2.csv, ..)

Comment: @jidma Yup , that's what i'm asking for :p

Comment: You could just do "select into [outfile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html) ...", which can generate .csv for you directly in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fputcsv appears to only be writing one row/record, and includes a row/record terminator in its output.  You will need to call fputcsv for each line of the report.

dbf's solution for a sequential filenaming works well in many cases.  Personally, I've found appending a timestamp helpful, as it requires less IO when there is a collection of existing files. Additionally, it makes it possible to know when the report was from without having to open each, even in the cases where the report was modified/copied/touched.

Minor detail: adjusted the query to just the columns your using.

```
<?php

require_once('connect_db.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT item_no, qty FROM sold_items");

$timestamp = date('Ymd-His'); 

$f = fopen("C:/mycsv-{$timestamp}.csv", 'w');

// Headers    
fputcsv($f, array('Item No', 'Qty'));

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    fputcsv($f, $row);
}
fclose($f);
```

Comment: Thank You ! I've tested your code and now I can see items and Qty are listed as columns but twice ! I mean suppose item_no is 8l900bk and qty is 12. I see it inside csv as ( 81900bk - 8l900bk - 12 - 12 )..So 4 columns instead of 2.

Comment: Your right.  mysql_fetch_array defaults to returning both numeric and assoc array.  Adjusted the code to only use numeric.

Comment: Hi rrehbein, is it possible to add table headers at the first row for each column. ( Item No - Qty ) then the rest of records will  be listed below. Sorry about that !

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```
$items_array[] = array($row['item_no'], $row['qty']);
```

second, use a variable to store the files name.

```
$filename = $name = "myscsv";
$index = 1;
while(file_exists($filename.".csv")) {
  $filename = $name.$index;
  $index++;
}
```

now you can save it ;)

```
$f = fopen("C:/{$filename}.csv", 'w');
```

Comment: Great, this actually works for creating another csv file. But is there a way to add my own save name ? Will this work if i send input text before clicking on submit. ( $_POST ) ?   Thank You !

Comment: you could use a hidden input <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="mysavename" /> and send it with the $_POST values, where $filename = $name = $_POST['filename'] .. if that is what you are trying to do ;)